# The index of every proper subgroup of a simple group containing an order 22 element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

The complete question is the following:

For $G$ a simple group containing an element of order $22$. Show that every proper subgroup of $G$ has index at least $13$.

I think I am supposed to use Sylow's Theorems to show this is true, but I don't know exactly what to do. Is it easier to show contradiction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Show that if $G$ is a simple group with a subgroup of index $n>1$, then $G$ injects into the symmetric group $S_n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @Ted As I see it we have that $22|n! \Rightarrow n\ge11$. Why is it $n\ge13$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $S_{12}$ has no element of order $22$.

Comment: Yes right! Thanks!